# Erro ao consultar WebService ConsultaCadastro2

Tags: web-service, soap

Estou a tentar automatizar as consultas ao Sintegra, aqui na minha empresa. Estou tentando implementar em VB.NET (linguagem do software da empresa), a consulta através do webService disponibilizado pelo sefaz (https://sef.sefaz.rs.gov.br/ws/cadconsultacadastro/cadconsultacadastro2.asmx)

No entanto, no momento de chamar o serviço, passando o cabeçalho e a mensagem, o VS me retorna o seguinte erro:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: SOAP header Action
>   was not understood.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderHandling.SetHeaderMembers(SoapHeaderCollection
>   headers, Object target, SoapHeaderMapping[] mappings,
>   SoapHeaderDirection direction, Boolean client)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Já pesquisei em vários fóruns sobre uma solução. Até agora nada.

Comment: Poste seu código, é necessário...

Comment: o codigo não coube aqui. Vou disponibilizar o link de download pelo dropBox https://www.dropbox.com/s/6g31g0hzav8lf8y/codigo.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acessar web services via .NET siga os seguintes passos:

1. Clique com o botão direito do mouse no projeto e selecione "Add Web References..."
2. Coloque a URL do Web Service.

Agora, basta instanciar o objeto do Web Service como um objeto e chamar os métodos do Web Services.

Pelo o que eu vi no seu código, você está criando a chamada do Web Service manualmente, o que dificulta muito a manutenção do código.

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo. Refiz o código e deu certo. Me bati um pouco no xml, pois o mesmo é case Sensitive. Agradeço a atenção!